# Using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection from powershell to execute contents of a SQL file with returned results

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, powershell, docker-compose

Before I start I have looked at Invoke-Sqlcmd and I suppose I could go down that route, but I would like to update the current script without having to change to different CMD-lets etc.

So my issue/use case is...

I have a docker container that has a health check script powershell file.
This file uses System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to create a connection to the DB and runs a basic query to check if the sql instance is running.

What I want to do is, once the health check logic is successful, run the contents of another .sql script file to seed the DB with some data.

health_check.ps1

```
$server = 'cas,1433'
$username = 'sa'
$password = 'myPass'
$database = 'cas'


try {
  $connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password"
  $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $connectionString
  $connection.Open()
  $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
  $command.CommandText = "SELECT 1"
  $result = $command.ExecuteScalar()

  if ($result -eq 1) {
    Write-Host "Success on health"
    # Run the contents of a file called seed_data.ps1 (The file is in the directory as this script)
    # assign the returned results from the script to $out
    Write-Host $out
    $connection.Close()
    exit 0
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "Health Failed"
    $connection.Close()
    exit 1
  }
}
catch {
  Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
  $connection.Close()
  exit 1
}
```

Side note. The docker compose file runs the health check on a loop, for example it runs every 10 seconds for a total of 10 times. So the issue isn't that the health check isn't working its just about getting the contents of the seed file to run.

Comment: "once the health check logic is successful, run the contents of another .sql script file" so what's stopping you? Just start another `SqlCommand` and do `$command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Im not sure how to reach into the seed_data.sql file to run its contents will go read up on ExecuteNonQuery quick tho.

Comment: `$script = Get-Content -Path "C:\whatever"; $command = [SqlCommand]::new($script, $connection); $command.ExecuteNonQuery();` something like that?

Comment: Let me check and see if it works. If it does I will let you know then you can post it as an answer for me to accept.

Comment: This was very close and got me some of the way. I ended up doing a Get-Content from the file. Setting it as the command and then doing ExecuteNonQuery.

If you want to add that as an answer then I will be happy to accept it. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction @Charlieface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the script from the file, and put it into a command. Use the `-Raw` option to get one big string.

```
using namespace System.Data.SqlClient;
# etc
```

```
$script = Get-Content -Path "C:\whatever" -Raw;
$command = [SqlCommand]::new($script, $connection);
$command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Generally don't bother "trying" the server with a separate `SELECT 1`. Just do what you need to do, if it works good, otherwise it'll just go the `catch`.

Comment: Thanks  @Chalieface. Your direction saved me a bunch of time.